# HTTP Digest authentication failing with '400 Bad Request' after a while

Tags: java, wildfly, httpurlconnection, digest-authentication

I have a problem with HTTP digest authentication on a Java client. I'm running a Web Service (SOAP) client on Wildfly, but the same problem occurs if I use URL.openConnection(), ie. the failing part is the underlying sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection and its authentication handling. I'm setting the credentials through java.net.Authenticator.

```
    java.net.Authenticator.setDefault(new java.net.Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected java.net.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new java.net.PasswordAuthentication("username", "password");
        }
    });

    URL url = new URL(requestUri);

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(Proxy.NO_PROXY);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    while (rd.readLine() != null) { }
    rd.close();
```

All is running well initially, but after a couple of weeks, all the HTTP calls gets response '400 Bad request' from the server. If I restart the JVM all the calls work again. The only thing I can think of is that the server thinks that there is something wrong with the digest auth (such as an incorrect nonce counter) and responds with HTTP 400. HttpURLConnection (or actually Authenticator?) does not understand HTTP 400 as failed authentication and continues to use the same auth tokens. After restarting JVM the calls naturally request new server nonce and starts nonce counter from 0, and everything works again.

Is there something I can do? Is there something I'm doing wrong? Can I somehow force the underlying JRE implementation to either understand HTTP 400 as failed authentication or to force the client to request new server nonce for all requests?

The server I'm making the request to is MS Dynamics NAV. Another section of my app is making similar HTTP requests to the same server but using the Apache HTTP Client, and there are no problems whatsoever.

**Update**:
I'm running Oracle's Server JRE 8u152

Comment: Which Java version and distribution do you use at runtime?

Comment: I'm running Server JRE 8u152